# MonoTouch binding derived from MKAnnotation

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm in the process of trying to create a binding for the WikitudeAPI in order to provide AR capabilities in my app.

So far I've tried to keep it very simple, I'm just binding a few of the methods and the minimum of classes. One of the classes is declared as such

```
@interface WTPoi : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {

}
```

To create the binding I've declared my binding as

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.MapKit;
namespace AR {
  [BaseType(typeof(MKAnnotation))]
  interface WTPoi {
  }
}
```

When I run btouch against it I get the an abort trap error
"line 2:  1959 Abort trap"

I've tried using other types as the BaseType just to see and they mostly work, any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that its a bug in the [Model] inheritance in btouch.

Declaring the interface as:

```
namespace AR {
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    public interface WTPoi {
        [Export ("coordinate")]
        CLLocationCoordinate2D Coordinate { get; set; }

        [Export ("title")]
        string Title { get; }

        [Export ("subtitle")]
        string Subtitle { get; }
    }  
}
```

Works fine but you lose the inheritance from MKAnnotation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get an abort trap error with your code but I wasn't successful. However, you surely have one error in the api definition.

Replace

```
[BaseType(MKAnnotation)]
```

with:

```
[BaseType(typeof(MKAnnotation))]
```

Comment: Sorry that was jut a typo in the post, the definition im trying has typeof in it correctly.

Comment: Which version of Mono/MonoTouch are you using? I'm running Mono 2.10 and MonoTouch 3.2.6 and get this message every time.

Comment: I have 4.0b with Mono 2.10.1. It compiles with btouch without errors.

Comment: Tried this on another mac and get a proper error message this time:

AR.WTPoi does not implement inherited abstract member MonoTouch.MapKit.MKAnnotation.Coordinate.get
AR.WTPoi does not implement inherited abstract member MonoTouch.MapKit.MKAnnotation.Coordinate.get

Fine thats better but I can't work out how to specify that I want to override Coordinate in my class.

Comment: You have to implement the members of the object you need to bind. You will find extensive information here: http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Binding_New_Objective-C_Types

Comment: I've read that but the problem is that MKAnnotation is abstract and it needs Coordinate implemented but if I specify it as part of the interface then btouch complains about it not being marked as override and since it's an interface I can't see how to do it.

Comment: You can specify that a property is an override bu adding an [Override] attribute to the appropriate property